# what it is: int (*z())[5];

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

```
int (*z())[5];
```

what is this? if I put it before main as global declaration it compiles. I thought z() would be a pointer ( **"z()"** )so tried:

```
int itab[5]={0,1,2,3,4};
((z())[0])[0]=itab;
```

this gives error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’

so I thought aha, so I am close and tried: `((z())[0])[0]=*itab;`
which compiles but gives linker unresolved symbol error:

> g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppappl_example4
>   build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o   build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:
>   In function `main': /NetBeansProjects/cppappl_example4/main.cpp:242:
>   undefined reference to`z()'

so my question is: is this declaration correct? if yes, then what it is, how to use it?

---

EDIT:
links given in answers are indeed of great help:

[nice rule of spiral by David Anderson](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

[and cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/)

thanks!

Comment: `z` is a function taking no arguments, and returning a pointer to an array of 5 `int`s.

Comment: Works great: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: @chris: The spiral rule... well, if you are able to apply it you don't need it, if you need it it will fail in complex situations. And it might not even be easy to find where to start the spiral!!!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Could you give me an example of where it wouldn't work. It's aided me in figuring out every complex declaration I've seen since reading it.

Comment: @chris: The problem is that the rule is too simplistic, and to be able to apply it you need to understand more than it's stated. If you just follow the definitions in that page, the interpretation of `char * const a[10][10];` would be that `a` is an array of 10 `const` array of 10 pointer to `char`... of course, with experience you understand when to spiral and when not to and transform into *array of 10 arrays of 10 constant pointers to `char`*, but that is hardly *spiral*... I prefer to start from the center (name) and grow *outwards* with no implied *spiral*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I see your point. I always thought of that as a single token when applying the rule, probably due to my experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int (*z())[5];
```

That is a function `z()` returning a pointer to an array of 5 int `int (*)[5]`.

```
((z())[0])[0]=itab;
```

The left hand side calls the function (declared before) and yields an `int (*)[5]` (call it `x`), which you dereference with `x[0]` (that translates to `*(x+0)`, effectively `*x`) yielding an array of 5 int (call it `y`) that you again dereference with `y[0]`, yielding an *lvalue* referring to the first element, and thus a `int&`.

The right hand side is an *lvalue* of type array of 5 int. Which will decay to a pointer to int `int*`, so checking only the types you have: `int & = int *`, which is not valid.

If you add the `[0]` to the right hand side, that causes the dereference and yields an *lvalue* referring to the first element in `itab`, which is of type `int`, and now the expression makes sense (type wise) as it is `int & = int`.

Now the problem is that you have not defined the function `z` anywhere so the linker complains.

> is this declaration correct? if yes, then what it is, how to use it?

It is correct, whether it is wanted or not is a different thing. A possible definition of `z` could be:

```
typedef int int5[5]; // simplify syntax later on
int5* z() {
  static int array[5] = {}; 
  return &array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a function returning a pointer to an array of five `ints`.